# I wonder using INNER JOIN and equality operator is faster or using IN when I try to filter data from a table by another table's column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, query-performance

While I'm trying to get all accounts, which received message from `foo@gmail.com`. I want to know about the performance of two following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM account
WHERE
    account_id in (
        SELECT distinct account_id
        FROM message mes
        WHERE mes.sender = 'foo@gmail.com'
    )
```

or

```
SELECT distinct account.*
FROM account acc
    INNER JOIN message mes
        ON mes.account_id = acc._id
WHERE
    mes.sender = 'foo@gmail.com'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just run them both and see for yourself

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) if you use `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` you will see the timings as well

Comment: It run too fast, so I don't know which is better in the future

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: The `join` second syntax can be faster than `in` for large amounts of data but you always need to test. Never make assumptions. `exists` can be even faster. It depends how smart the query planner is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the first query in such situations. Don't use `DISTINCT` inside an `IN` clause subquery, though. Don't try to tell the DBMS how to perform the `IN`. (Well, a good DBMS should simply ignore the `DISTINCT` and make up its own mind how to look up the rows.)

```
SELECT *
FROM account
WHERE account_id IN (SELECT account_id FROM message mes WHERE mes.sender = 'foo@gmail.com');
```

Ideally you'd have an index on `message (sender, account_id)`. The message table itself wouldn't even have to be read. The sender is looked up in the index, then all matching account IDs taken. With that you read the accounts and that's it. Without an index this is probably much slower, but still: Read the message table once, pick up the distinct account IDs, then read the accounts. No big deal.

With a join instead you'd combine all messages with their accounts. This can be quite a big intermediate result, which must be sorted to get distinct rows. A costly operation. And even if the DBMS is great with joins and sorting and does this extremely fast, then it can still use this same approach for the simple query with the `IN` clause. It's up to the DBMS to make a good plan and a perfect DBMS would come up with exactly the same plan for the two queries :-)

My advice: Only join when you are interested in the joined result. In your case you are not. You are interested in accounts matching some criteria, so write the query accordingly. Don't mutilate your queries, because of thinking the DBMS will use another slick approach then. It may even do this in the current DBMS version and stop doing this with the next update. Keep your queries as readable as possible. If you want accounts where a certain messages exists, use `WHERE` with `EXISTS` or `IN`. This is how SQL is supposed to be written.

Comment: At my school, my teacher taught me that JOIN is a costly query therefore I question this. Because my friends normally use second query.
I always want to deeply understand about my queries so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand some people don't like my question. In my class, my teacher had teach me that when we join a table, that action is very complicated because the size of result table could be bigger double, tripble or more than that.

Now we suppose some number:

- X = 1.000 record (1000 user) in `account` table.
- Y = 100 message that each account have.
- Z = 10 friends that each user have.
- T = 10.000 message in `message` table.

In the first query, when we search email `foo@gmail.com` in 10.000 records from `message` table. Then we will got 10 account_id that Foo had send to them. Now, when we search in table user, we will take  1.000 time to loop through every account and we will take 10 time to compare current acocunt_id with list 10 account_id that we found before.

> According to mathematics, complexibility of this query is: 10.000 + 1.000 * 10 <=> T + X * Z

In the second query, we join to table and the length of result table expect is 10.000 (because the relation between `account` table and `message` table is One To Many, so each message belong to only one account => the length of result table is equal to the length of `message` table), and query WHERE only take 1 time to compare.

> According to mathematics, complexibility of this query is: 10.000 <=> T.

But we don't see that the length of result table maybe extend double size. And I can't calculate the complexity of JOIN function. That is why I wrote this question.

Everyone can dislike my question. But I realy want to know about it.